# Search function to send all variations of the text uppercase an lowercase

Tags: search, uppercase

I have a function that uses an api to pull information based on the text given in the request.

The problem is that the text has to match the item exactly. Such as the item is named "Peach and Apple" and if you type "peach and apple" it will not return. You have to type "Peach and Apple" in order to properly request the item.

Is there a way I can send every variation of "Peach and Apple" (just incase is was something weird like "Peach and Le'Apple") with every variation of an uppercase letter?

I could make it uppercase every letter at the start of the string which is easy and would work with a lot of requests. Then I could uppercase every letter after a space which with the previous change would handle ALMOST every search.

The problem is I cannot make it uppercase every letter after a ' for this example(reason):

"Peach and Le'Apple" would work but "Peach and Apple's Leaf" would not work since the s is not uppercase. Thus is there a way to properly search for this?

Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: please edit your question and add the code that you have so far (in code blocks) also tag the question with the programming language that is being used

Comment: Do you have any influence with the API? Ability to use wildcards?

Comment: Which language or application are you using?

Comment: With <1K followers on the search tag and 3 on the uppercase tag, the only people likely to see this are reviewers.  If it's not about programming, it'll probably be deleted as off-topic eventually.  Read [ask] and [mcve] then do us a favor to save a lot of other reviewers having to read it.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured a way around it. The problem was that the items I was searching for had to be in the exact form. I was the one that saved those items from the api. So when I save them now I have 2 separate columns. One that saves the name with uppercase that will be what is shown on screen and another that saves the same name only purely converted to lowercase with toLowerCase(). This lets me search for the items and still keep the nice uppercase name without having to do some nasty logic I dont want to do.